# Excel is locked during C function calls through DLL

Tags: c, excel, function, dll

I'm callig C functions through a DLL file from Excel 2003 but notice that everthing in Excel is locked while the DLL is "active" (don't know how else to describe it). Is there anyway of "releasing" it. There are several C function calls through the DLL from Excel but in between these calls I want for example graphs in Excel to be updated. Excel will after a C function call write certain data to cells being source data for the graphs but the graphs don't get updated directly. The graphs are not updated until the program is finished.

Best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Basically not a good idea to do slow things in an XLL.

**Option 1: Pump Messages/DoEvents**

The C function must pump messages for Excel to be responsive.  However be aware that this makes the system re-entrant, which greatly complicates things. If an incoming message such as a button click occurs during your C function, it may cause the function to be called a second time, which may not be expected. (This depends on what your function is).

The Visual Basic equivalent is "DoEvents". In C it looks something like this:

```
void DoEvents()
{
    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,  0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
    { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

This will process all waiting messages (for mouse clicks, redrawing, and so on) until there are none left, then return. If there are no messages it will return immediately.

**Option 2: Be asynchronous**

The second option is to break down your function so it can run on a separate thread. Then you will either provide a callback to be called when the function is finished (via COM for example) or you can periodically poll to find out when the job has finished.